# Jose Encrypter returning nil

Tags: swift, jose

I am using [JOSESwift](https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift). When I use the Encrypter method it returns `nil` without details of any error. Below is my code sample. Can anyone please help why does the Encrypter method return `nil`?

Intention : I am trying to set wrapping key to my JWE object and from JOSESwift i can understand that Encrypter takes in that cek key.

```
// Jose implementation.
        let joseHeader = JWEHeader(algorithm: .direct,
                                   encryptionAlgorithm: .A128CBCHS256)
        let joseEncrypter = Encrypter(keyEncryptionAlgorithm: .RSAOAEP,
                                      encryptionKey: cekKeyData,
                                      contentEncyptionAlgorithm: .A128CBCHS256)!
        let josePayload = Payload(Data(base64Encoded: jsonString)!)

        let joseJWE = try? JWE(header: joseHeader, payload: josePayload, encrypter: joseEncrypter)
```

Comment: It returns nil because you've used `try?`. If you switch that to `try`, the error it throws will tell you what the problem is. `try?` specifically tells Swift to throw away the error and just return nil.

Comment: Method Encrypter returns nil which does not have any try on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're passing the wrong kind of key, or are incorrectly selecting `.RSAOAEP` as your algorithm and meant `.direct`.

```
///   - key: The key used to perform the encryption. If the `keyEncryptionAlgorithm` is `.direct`, the
///          `encryptionKey` is the shared symmetric content encryption key. Otherwise the `encryptionKey` is the
///           public key of the receiver. See [RFC-7516](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516#section-5.1) for
///           details.
```

`nil` is only returned in the following case from [that code](https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift/blob/764ea3b27683c5dc5bdb39ba450198b8e48d7a51/JOSESwift/Sources/Encrypter.swift#L81-L87) given the passed parameters:

```
switch (keyEncryptionAlgorithm, contentEncyptionAlgorithm) {
case (.RSA1_5, .A256CBCHS512), (.RSAOAEP, .A256CBCHS512), (.RSAOAEP256, .A256CBCHS512), (.RSA1_5, .A128CBCHS256), (.RSAOAEP, .A128CBCHS256), (.RSAOAEP256, .A128CBCHS256):
    guard type(of: key) is RSAEncrypter.KeyType.Type else {
        return nil
    }
    // ...
```

This indicates that the `cekKeyData` is not of type RSAEncrypter.KeyType. I suspect it's a generated AES key instead.

Comment: The cekKeyData is a shared key created from ECDHSecret. i am trying to setWrappingKey to my JWE and that was the original intention to do this. Please help.

Comment: if its AES key then does JOSESwift does not support this ?

Comment: You've requested the encryptor to encrypt with RSAOAEP, and then passed it an AES key. You need to pass it an RSA key if you want to wrap using RSA-OAEP. If you're using a shared secret, then I don't understand why you're also using RSA-OAEP. Shared secrets are "direct" encryption and don't require key wrapping. I'm not familiar with JOSESwift particularly; I typically use cjose.

Comment: I think your answer is right for what question i have asked. The key what i am passing is definitely not AESEncrypter.KeyType thats the reason for getting nil back. I need to now figure out what is the key type i am passing for my code to work.

Comment: @Max were you able to figure out what key/algorithm configuration you need? Robs answer is likely correct and you just didn't pass a key that matches the specified algorithms. If you want to use a shared encryption key make sure to select the `.direct` key encryption key (just as you did in the JOSEHeader configuration).

Comment: Yes Robs answer is right. What i was trying was using a EC key with JOSE Swift which is currently not supported. That was the reason for the encryptor to return nil.